# Toggle class on an element's parent's previous sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

When certain elements are clicked, I want to toggle a class on that element's parent's previous sibling (not all, just one), where that sibling doesn't have a specific class ('item') already.

HTML:

```
<tr id="product1">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item" id="sku1">
    <td>SKU</td>
    <td class="valueButton">Button</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr id="product2">
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item" id="sku2">
    <td>SKU</td>
    <td class="valueButton">Button</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
<tr class="item" id="sku3">
    <td>SKU</td>
    <td class="valueButton">Button</td>
    <td>Text</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on({
    click: function () {
        $('tr', $(this).parent().prev(":not('.item')")).toggleClass('blueChecked');
    }
}, "tr.item td:not('.valueButton')");
```

Comment: Why aren't you nesting the items within the product?   That would make it so much easier.

Comment: Nested tables cause a performance hit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`.prevAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll) and keep the first only..

```
$(this).parent().prevAll(':not(.item)').first().toggleClass('blueChecked');
```

The `prev` that you use only check the immediately previous element. The selector is tested against that one element if matches the it is kept.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/UtJPS/

Comment: Thank you, that works perfectly and fits in with my existing code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might do it:

```
$('table').on('click', 'td', function () {
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $last = $tr.siblings()
        .filter(':not(.item)')
        .filter(':lt('+ $tr.index() + ')')
        .last();
    if ($last.length) {
        $last.toggleClass('blueChecked');
    }
});
```